# C Lang: files have $\002, example 2023_12_15_'$''\002'this is a test file.md

Tags: c

My C program:

- takes arguments and converts them into a string; and
- prepends a date.

I am removing punctuation and upper case letters via a loop using C's int arrays for string representation.

When I type:

```
    ./cprog -md I am cre,ating a .md file
```

I am expecting:

```
    2023_12_15_i_am_cre_ating_a__md_file.md
```

I am receiving:

```
    '2023_12_15_'$''\002'i_am_cre_ating_a__md_file.md'
```

I am removing punctuation via:

```c
    for ( int arg = 0; arg < argc; arg++ ){

        for ( int let = 0; let < strlen(argv[arg]); let++ ){

            if ( !ispunct( argv[arg][let] ) ){

                argv[arg][let] = tolower( argv[arg][let] );

            } else {

                argv[arg][let] = 95;

            }

        }

        strcat( filename, argv[arg] );

    }
```

I am getting the date via:

```c
    time_t rawtime = time(NULL);
    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&rawtime);
    char filename_date[12];
    char result[ strlen(filename_date) + strlen(filename) ];
    strftime( filename_date, sizeof(filename_date), "%Y_%b_%d", ptm );
    sprintf( result, "%s_%s.md", filename_date, filename );
    strcpy( filename, result );
    create_md( filename );
```

75% of the time the above code works.

25% of the time, and unknown to me why at this time, the code produces" '$''\002' in between the date and the string.

I believe that is a start string character.

How do I stop files from appearing like:

```
    '2023_12_15_'$''\002'i_am_cre_ating_a__md_file.md'
```

Comment: Please try to create a single cohesive [mre] to show us.

Comment: As a hint: `char filename_date[12];` does not initialize the array. Its contents will be *indeterminate*. More specifically, it can't be considered a null-terminated string, so can't be passed to functions like `strlen`. The size of `result` is also too small, since you have extra characters in your `sprintf` that aren't accounted for when you create `result`.

Comment: if I remove "[12]" from filename_date I get a compilation error of array size missing. I added 5 characters which accounts for the extra characters. I also, increase results.  None of that had an impact.  I feel like the issue is the closing null character is probably missing on the date.

Comment: I recommend you use `snprintf` to create the resulting string. That will allow you to get the actual length required (by passing a `NULL` destination pointer and a zero size), use that size (plus one) to create the `result` array. Then use `snprintf` again to actually write to `result`. And make sure that `filename` is at least as big as `result`. Or better yet, use `result` directly in the call to `create_md` instead of copying over to `filename`.

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure that `filename` is big enough for all arguments? And that it's properly initialized as a null-terminated string (otherwise `strcat` will not work)? Also note that you include `argv[0]` in the file name, but it's the command-name and shouldn't usually be included.

Comment: As a ***guess*** (since you won't show us a [mre]), `filename` is not initialized.

Comment: Since when does `%b` produce `12`? Are you actually using `%m` (which makes more sense here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to debug my issue.

I was iterating over the char array using "ispunct()" to determine if the content is alpha or not.  However, I am copying start string and end string markers from multiple strings into a single string.

Switching to "if( variable >= 'a' && variable <= 'z' )" allowed me to properly build the string and control when the null character is in the string.

(A thanks to all those who contributed to the conversation.  Your improvements also was a part of the success).

Comment: Please mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's several problems, all having to do with memory allocation.

```
    char filename_date[12];
    char result[ strlen(filename_date) + strlen(filename) ];
    strftime( filename_date, sizeof(filename_date), "%Y_%b_%d", ptm );
    sprintf( result, "%s_%s.md", filename_date, filename );
```

`strlen` works by reading memory until it sees a null byte.

`filename_date` is uninitialized, which means it could contain any old garbage.

`strlen(filename_date)` will read the garbage until it happens to see a null byte. It does not know how much memory has been allocated to `filename_date` and will just keep reading past 12 bytes if necessary. It can return any number from 0 to something very large. If `filename_date` contains all nulls then `strlen(filename_date)` will be 0 and `result` will be too small to fit both `filename_date` and `filename` resulting in undefined behavior.

You can fix this by using `sizeof(filename_date)` instead.

That's your first problem. This is your second problem:

```
    strcpy( filename, result );
```

You're copying the contents of `result` into `filename`, but `result` can potentially contain a string which is larger than `filename` has memory allocated for it. This will also result in undefined behavior.

You can solve this by leaving `filename` alone and passing `result` straight into `create_md()`.

---

There may be additional memory problems in your code. Using a [memory sanitizer](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/05/05/memory-error-checking-in-c-and-c-comparing-sanitizers-and-valgrind) can help find them.

Comment: "uninitialised" can you elaborate? What is the best practice?

Comment: @Nully, The problem isn't that it's uninitialized, but that you that you read from it when it's initialized (by using `strlen(filename_date)`). The fix is to replace or move `strlen(filename_date)` which is wrong anyway.

Comment: I tried changing the ‘strlen()’ to a ‘sizeof()’, which has resulted in memory segmentation error. 

What is the preferred method of initializing an variable?

Comment: @Nully If you're still learning things like variable initialization, you likely have many memory problems in your code. Fixing one will expose another. I think you need to take a step back and do some reading and tutorials and exercises about how memory management works in C. Or pick a more forgiving language like Python or Ruby to accomplish your task; they take care of this for you.

Comment: @Schwern for sure. No ego here. I am maybe like 3-hours into porting a bash script. I am a noob learning the hard way for sure.